# optimization problem gaussian maximizes entropy

Tags: probability, probability-theory, optimization, convex-optimization, information-theory

Let $X_1, X_2, Z_1$ be random variables and define $$Y=aX_1+bX_2+Z_1$$ I have the following optimization problem of difference of entropies,

$$f=\max_{p(x_1x_2)} h(Y) - h(Y|X_2)= \max_{p(x_1,x_2)} h(aX_1+bX_2+Z_1)-h(aX_1+Z_1|X_2)$$ Note that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not independent and so we can't simplify to the following easier optimization problem $$g=\max_{} h(Y)-h(Z_1)$$ where g can be easily shown to be an upperbound on f and easily shown to admit a jointly gaussian distribution as optimal solution.

My question is can I say that since g is an upperbound on $f$, then jointly gaussian is also optimal for the optimization problem $f$?

Comment: If $X_1$ and $X_2$ were independent then the objective function would become $\max_{p(x_1)p(x_2)}(h(Y)-h(aX_1+Z_1))$ and not $g$. (If that was the case then you would have the answer to your problem!)

Comment: The optimal joint distribution for your problem is of the form $p(x_1,x_2)=p(x_2)\delta(x_1-x_2)$, i.e., $X_1$ and $X_2$ are identical. This makes sense since we are interested in maximizing the mutual information of the communication link between $X_2$ and $Y$ with $X_1$ acting as an assistant by "retransmitting" $X_2$. Under this approach, the problem boils down to the classic AWGN communication problem, and capacity is achieved by a Gaussian $X_2$.

Comment: g can be reached by adding to the conditioning in f the random variables $X_1$ by (conditioning reduces entropy )and so I can write down g...